# SB Audigy Rx with Jack in Ubuntu Studio Disco Dingo

Tags: 19.04, ubuntu-studio, jack

Right... Firstly sorry for the wall of text... the commands I ran were ones I saw others asking people to run to help fix their issue...

I am running the latest ubuntu studio Disco Dingo 19.04

I am looking to get Jack audio playback setup and I am unsure of how to set up my card as there are loads of different options I can pick from.

[image: list of audio outputs too long]

I am unsure which one to pick and I get confused which ones I've tried.

can anyone help me out?

commands run below... is there anything else I can try to set this up?

Running:     `aplay --list-devices`

gets:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Audigy2 [SB Audigy 5/Rx [SB1550]], device 0: emu10k1 [ADC Capture/Standard PCM Playback]
  Subdevices: 31/32
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
  Subdevice #8: subdevice #8
  Subdevice #9: subdevice #9
  Subdevice #10: subdevice #10
  Subdevice #11: subdevice #11
  Subdevice #12: subdevice #12
  Subdevice #13: subdevice #13
  Subdevice #14: subdevice #14
  Subdevice #15: subdevice #15
  Subdevice #16: subdevice #16
  Subdevice #17: subdevice #17
  Subdevice #18: subdevice #18
  Subdevice #19: subdevice #19
  Subdevice #20: subdevice #20
  Subdevice #21: subdevice #21
  Subdevice #22: subdevice #22
  Subdevice #23: subdevice #23
  Subdevice #24: subdevice #24
  Subdevice #25: subdevice #25
  Subdevice #26: subdevice #26
  Subdevice #27: subdevice #27
  Subdevice #28: subdevice #28
  Subdevice #29: subdevice #29
  Subdevice #30: subdevice #30
  Subdevice #31: subdevice #31
card 2: Audigy2 [SB Audigy 5/Rx [SB1550]], device 2: emu10k1 efx [Multichannel Capture/PT Playback]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 2: Audigy2 [SB Audigy 5/Rx [SB1550]], device 3: emu10k1 [Multichannel Playback]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Running: `lspci -v | grep -i audio`

gets

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
05:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs CA0108/CA10300 [Sound Blaster Audigy Series]
```

running : `cat /proc/asound/cards`

gets

```
 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xfe600000 irq 16
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfe080000 irq 36
 2 [Audigy2        ]: Audigy2 - SB Audigy 5/Rx [SB1550]
                      SB Audigy 5/Rx [SB1550] (rev.0, serial:0x10241102) at 0xc000, irq 37
 3 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - Live Streaming USB Device
                      eEver Live Streaming USB Device at usb-0000:09:00.0-1, super speed
 4 [MIXER5         ]: USB-Audio - JUST MIXER5
                      C-Media Electronics Inc. JUST MIXER5 at usb-0000:02:00.0-1, full speed
 5 [C920           ]: USB-Audio - HD Pro Webcam C920
                      HD Pro Webcam C920 at usb-0000:02:00.0-2.2, high speed
```

Running: `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0403]'`

gets

```
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1002:4383] (rev 40)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1458:a132]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [1458:3682]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

running : `pactl list short sinks`

gets

```
2   jack_out    module-jack-sink.c  float32le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Comment: isn't the first SB the right one? try that one. you want a playback device only (I think)

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely hardware-specific question. I recommend trial-and-error. There's no harm in experimenting to find which one works for your device.

Comment: Yeah... I think I need to look into jack a lot more...